# What difference between exposed library modules and dependency modules in Cabal?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, hint

I am testing **hint** library which does magic thing - evaluates Haskell code in runtime! The library is working almost as expected, but following deviation raised a question in my head.

Let's say there is a typical new stack project from a template with *app* and *library*. Dependence of app on library is described same way as any other package (base, text, lens, etc), but Haskell script file cannot import modules residing in the library of the same stack package, meanwhile modules from hackage libraries such as *process* library are resolved without any issue for the script.

Module required inside a script becomes available once I extract it into a stack sub packages.

So, is there a linking trick voiding extra stack sub package?

[link the issue on Github](https://github.com/haskell-hint/hint/issues/125)

Comment: Is your app running in a context where GHC (of whatever version hint is using) knows that your library is installed? Stack (and cabal! no slight on stack here) does funny things with GHC package environments.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `stack install` to install your package into the package database.